# How to use a variable to select a row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a Macro in Excel to take the data from 2 different departments and putting them into the same sheet to use the data for pivot tables. The data is automatically separated onto different sheets by departments when I run the report. The problem I keep running into is the amount of data (rows used) is always changing.

I've got it to a working point where I can get a variable set for that last row, but I cant figure out how to actually implement it. I might need to go one more row down from what it shows. I don't know how I should go about that either. Here's what I have for the affiliated code. Any advise would be great!

```
    Sheets("30A").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Range("A1:O1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
With ActiveSheet
    Dim lastRow30A As Long
    lastRow30A = Sheet1.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
End With
    Sheets("40A").Select
    Range("A2:O2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Range("lastRow30A").Select
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid the use of `Select` and `Activate` they slow the code:

```
With Sheets("30A")
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp)).Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
End With

Dim lastRow30A As Long
lastRow30A = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

With Sheets("40A")
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp)).Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lastrow30, 1)
End With
```

Comment: If I followed along with your code then it replaces mine that I posted. So I commented out save my old code for reference and pasted in yours. I get a Compile error: Invalid or unqualified reference on the ```.Rows``` that defines the ```lastRow30A``` variable